# Ruby on Rails - Can I modify data before it is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quick example: A user enters a username into a form, and I need to make that text username before storing it in the app's database, thereby making it permanently lowercase.

Where would I put this code, and how would I access the data to be lowercased?

Thanks.

Answer (score 86):

you should overwrite the attribute writer:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def username=(val)
    write_attribute(:username, val.downcase)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is the better solution. It will ensure consistency even before an object is saved to the database.

Answer (score 53):

You could use one of ActiveRecords callbacks in your User model, eg something like that:

```
before_save { |user| user.username = user.username.downcase }
```

Comment: More on ActiveRecord callbacks: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: If you have many hooks like that and/or many operations performed on attributes you can also create methods for them and give the method names instead of lambdas.

You may also see [attribute-filters](http://rubydoc.info/gems/attribute-filters/1.2.2/) gem that simplifies that process if you have many callbacks that are designed to change attributes.

Answer (score 19):

In your User model (models/user.rb), take advantage of ActiveRecord callbacks:

```
before_save do
  self.username = self.username.downcase
end
```

Comment: The second self (in `self.username.downcase`) is redundant.

Comment: hey @janosrusiczki could you explain (or point to a resource where explains) why the second `self` is redundant?
Honestly, I'm also struggling why the first one is required too.

Answer (score 7):

I spent a while looking up a bug stopping me from utilizing this code. My database was rolling back every time I tried to intercept an attribute and change it to `false` before saving.

I'm contributing my answer here because this thread was the first Google result for accomplishing this task but didn't cover the whole returning `false` problem.

If any of your callbacks return `false` everything will be rolled back in the db.

I was trying to set an Offer to be created to not be accepted in the database or `@offer.accepted = false`. The problem was that this line caused the whole method to return false and rollback the entire process.

I fixed it by tossing in an implicit return `true` afterwards

Code that worked:

`before_save {|offer| offer.accepted = false; true}`

Takeaway: Your callbacks can't return `false` if you want them to succeed.

Source: [rails 3 : Do i need to give return true in a before_save callback for an object.save to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735141/rails-3-do-i-need-to-give-return-true-in-a-before-save-callback-for-an-object)

Answer (score 6):

```
def username=(str)
 super(str.downcase)
end
```

I thought this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, The submit button on the form should delegate to a controller action
where params[:user_name] is available. You could lowercase that before doing a 
SomeModel.update(params) or create(params).

So you could do it in the controller action.

Comment: You need to think about the consequences of tightly coupling the controller and the model. What happens when two controllers need to create an instance of this model? What about using the console to create a user, and the developer forgets that usernames ought to be downcase? What about unit testing? I think a better approach is to use the ActiveRecord callbacks as suggested by effkay.

Comment: Yes I upvoted him too. My reasoning : As long as its in one-place I dont really care. it didn't really look like there were multiple places from the OP's question.. so i went for the simplest thing that could possibly work. Also you may not always have a model.. in this scenario however it looks like the OP should be using one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an [Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) to the model and doing this action in the before_save method.  Then it is guaranteed to lowercase the username no matter which controller or action is creating it, and if there is an issue performing any action within the observer, an exception is thrown and the object won't save.

Edit: Please note that you **can't** do a Model.save within the before_save tied to that model, otherwise you end up in an infinite loop.  You'll need to do an update_attributes or something.